# create a timer using python.i cant understand the logic used to build a timer that prints "ok" after every 2 seconds in python. #while_loop

Tags: python

i cant understand the logic used to build a timer that prints "ok" after every 2 seconds in python. Also the body of the while loop . please explain
  `import time print("start") start=time.time() while True: end = time.time() if (end-start)>=2: print("ok") start=time.time()`

Answer (score 0):

There is two methods of doing that:

FIRST:

```
import time
while True:
    time.sleep(2)
    print('ok')
```

SECOND:

```
import time
oldtime = time.time()
while True:
    if oldtime + 2 == time.time(): #time.time() means current time
        print('ok')
        oldtime = time.time()
```

If your program must not pause(need to do other things) use the SECOND method if not try the FIRST one it is easy.

If you have any questions just comment this post.